# UITabBarController with UIViewController without tabbaritem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm new to iOS development and have such problem, if anybody can help me:
My project consist of a view (home view) and a tabbarcontroller with 3 views.
How can I make so, that home view will show tabbarcontroller, but without adding tabbar item to it, like this:

```
-------------    -------------    -------------    -------------
|   HOME    |    |  VIEW  1  |    |  VIEW 2   |    |  VIEW 3   |
|CONTROLLER |    |CONTROLLER |    |CONTROLLER |    |CONTROLLER | 
|           |    |           |    |           |    |           |
|           |    |           |    |           |    |           |    
|           |    |           |    |           |    |           |    
|           |    |           |    |           |    |           |    
-------------    -------------    -------------    -------------
|VC1|VC2|VC3|    |VC1|VC2|VC3|    |VC1|VC2|VC3|    |VC1|VC2|VC3|
-------------    -------------    -------------    -------------
```

Home view is UITableViewController. Also I'm using Storyboard, if it is important

Thanks

Comment: So you want home controller to not be in the tab bar controller, but to show a tab bar at the bottom (not tab bar controller as you said in your question)??

Comment: yes, home controller must not be in tabbarcontroller, but show tabbar at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to show a VC without adding to TabBarController like this.[may be you can hide it,its a guess didn't tried].

But i dont understand the purpose of home view in a tabBar controller?

Comment: the purpose of home view controller will the same as tabbaritems from tabbarcontroler, it will show a list of available VC, and when tapped will show respective VC, as will tap to tabbaritems

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tab bar to Home controller, and give the items the same names as what you have on your tab bar controller's tab bar. Home controller should be made the delegate of its tab bar, and you can implement the delegate method, tabBar:didSelectItem:, to switch to the proper controller.

It's not clear from your question how you want to get from the home controller to your tab bar controller, so it's hard to give you any more specific advice on how to switch to the right controller inside the tab bar controller.